# How to populate injected bean in jsf

Tags: jsf, dependency-injection, model, cdi

I have a simple form :

```
<h:form>
  <h:inputText value="#{storyController.story.author}"/>
  <h:commandButton action="#{storyController.save}" value="save"/>
</h:form>
```

and a bean like this :

```
@Model
public class Story {

    private String author;

    //getter and setter...
}
```

and a controller :

```
@Model
public class StoryController {

    private StoryService storyService;

    private Story story;

    @Inject
    public StoryController(StoryService storyService, Story story) {
        this.storyService = storyService;
        this.story = story;
    }

    public String save() {
        System.out.println(story.getAuthor());

        return "index.xhtml";
    }

    public Story getStory() {
        return story;
    }

    public void setStory(Story story) {
         this.story = story;
    }
}
```

Now when I fill the author field and click on save button, the bean is not populated (the bean is injected correctly, it's not null).
If instead I do story = new Story() in constructor, then the bean is correctly populated. I want to avoid doing, this, I think that injecte bean is a better practice right?
I tried to set input value like : #{story.author} but still not populated.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: using `@Model` on your controller makes it implicitly `@RequestScope`d. You should choose a longer living scope such as `@ConversationScope`. Otherwise your `Controller` (and therefore the story-settings) will not survive the request, caused by calling `save()`.

Comment: I tried, I also tried an ApplicationScope on the Controller and same result.

Comment: try to change the managedBean (StoryController ) `@Model` by `@Named
@RequestScoped` (it's true i am using a RequestScoped but you can find other scope available).

Comment: you can find a complete example [Cargo tracker](https://cargotracker.java.net/)

Comment: I think the main problem is that both - `Story` and `StoryController` are `@RequestScoped`. Therefore, the data is lost right after the request. Try working with `@SessionScoped` instead. It makes a lot more sense to store this data for the length of one session rather than one request.

Comment: I tried to put Story in session scope, but the problem still occurs and I don't think it makes more sense to store this object in session scope, the goal is juste to fill a form, and put the object in a database. The object live only during the request.

Comment: I put`StoryController` in `@ApplicationScoped` still not populate.